# How to fix this image in bottom middle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

I put a picture more clearly understand what they want to do.

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/10/scroll.png">
        </div>
```

There is positioned in that position ... and I did these things with bootstrap, somehow you know how to fix this problem?

This picture must always be there regardless of resolution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you would like it aligned to the bottom of the image?

Comment: yes,You understand well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

Add position relative to the container

```
.about-content-top{
    position:relative;
}
```

Add position absolute to the images and set bottom to 0

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;" class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2015/10/scroll.png">
</div>
```